# Equivalent of html "<strong>" tag in WPF?

Tags: html, wpf, flowdocument

I have html file containing text with strong tag can say `<strong>Windows Presentation Framework</strong>`. I want to implement strong tag in flow document of WPF. I tried by setting font weight property to bold but not find an expected result/output as in html file. Any clue or hint on how to do it?

For `<b>` tag i tried with :

```
flowdocument.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

I am trying to say whether I am go for class FontWeights(`Bold` or `ExtraBold` or `SemiBold` or `Normal`) or class FontStretches(`Expanded` or `SemiExpanded` or `ExtraExpanded` or `Normal`)

Comment: "but not find an expected result", what does that mean? Did the text segment appear in bold font or not?

Comment: Thanks for reply . ya it appears as bold.So you mean to say <b> and <strong> are same for wpf

Comment: `b` and `strong` are the same in HTML as well, `b` is legacy mark-up that breaks the separation of structure and presentation and `strong` bears semantic meaning, it is not primarily stylistic device. I can't comment on the difference of font-weight and font-stretch in wPF, thought, hopefully someone chimes in with an explanation for curious.

Comment: Could it be that `stretch` is computed while `weight` is defined in the font file similarly like (if I'm not mistaken) `oblique` is computed geometrically while `italic` is defined in the font file by the designer?

Answer (score 0):

Your content should look like this in XAML:

```
<FlowDocument><Paragraph><Bold>Windows Presentation Foundation</Bold></Paragraph></FlowDocument>
```

Have a look at the link below for more information on FlowDocument structure - it has it's own markup scheme like HTML (except it's XML): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970786(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:** To the downvoters - copy and paste this code into any XAML designer - it is **CORRECT**! It achieves the same typographic effect as `<strong>` in HTML.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Bold>Windows Presentation Foundation</Bold>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it may looks like same but for me the length of the text(means in pixel) meters